# Regexp doesn't support negative lookahead? Any workarounds?

Tags: sphinx, regex-lookarounds

Trying to do a version of this for regexp:

```
brown fox(?! that)
```

But I get:

```
re2/re2.cc:534: Invalid RE2: invalid perl operator: (?!
```

Is there a work around for this as the negative words are key here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely a bodge, but just reverse the unneeded replacement?

```
regexp_filter = brown fox => blabla
regexp_filter = blabla that => brown fox that
```

Maybe?

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up doing, it is something of a bodge however and adds overhead.